# Any tools to cross check whether all the magento enterprise code has been removed from the community edition after the downgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have downgraded one site from **magento** enterprise to community edition based on the below blogs/forums, after that we have made few changes to the site work perfectly in the community edition. And the site working fine now and it's live with community version.

https://gist.github.com/ProxiBlue/87208724f758d5da472f http://www.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/

And we have applied for the Certification of Compliance to the magento team to close the enterprise agreement, however we got the reply from the magento team there are still few elements related to enterprise code still in the site and needs to be clean up to close the agreement.

We have cross checked the site very closely but we are unable to find a code/option related to enterprise code, even we have requested to the enterprise team to provide the documents/reports which show the enterprise code still in the site but it seems like they will receive the status as true/false, that's it. They don't have any other details.

And let us know, is there any proper tool or suggestions to cross check and find the enterprise code with the site.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: It will be better if you ask the Magento team for specific inputs so it will be helpful for your team to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite all files by the community edition and after that search for the phrase "Magento Enterprise Edition" that is in all Magento Enterprise files description comment.